# VSTS Release - Copy Files from subfolder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a "Release" that I intend to use to publish to a remote share.

I have created a `Copy Files` task which works.  However my build artifacts are all below two subfolders `[UI] Build/drop`. I want to copy the contents of the drop folder rather than the entire thing. Unfortunately I only seem to be able to copy the entire thing!

Task (copies all files and folders):

- Source Folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/`
- Contents: `**`
- Target Folder: `\\myshare\test`

So I tried to only copy the contents ([with support from this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files)) of `UIBuild/drop` but nothing gets copied in any of these cases:

- Changing `Source Folder` to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/[UI] Build/Drop`.
- Keeping `Source Folder` as it was but changing `Contents` to `[UI] Build/drop/**`
- Keeping `Source Folder` as it was but changing `Contents` to `**/[UI] Build/drop/**`
- Keeping `Source Folder` as it was but changing `Contents` to `**/drop/**`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I realised its because there was a square bracket in my artifact.  Once I changed my artifact to not use the square bracket everything started working.

Im not sure if its related but [this post](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/issues/60) on minimatch within gulp helped give me the nod